# Deleting last line from notepad++ files

Tags: regex, notepad++

I am having a small problem regarding removal of last line from text files. I have over 500 text files and in each of them the last line is simply blank. I want to find some quick method to delete these empty lines. I am looking for some search and replace method to remove these lines.
[image: Empty lines at end of every file]

So far I have tried searching `\r\n` and other methods but nothing works. Only thing that works is by going to edit->line operations-> Remove Empty Lines but it is cumbersome to do this individually for each file.

So is there any way to achieve this?

Ahmar

Comment: Are you going to do it manually or are you writting some small script/application to do it?

Comment: Of course I want some regex solution or some search and replace files

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a try with:

Find what: `\n$`
Replace with: NOTHING

Comment: Thanks a lot man . It works like a charm. Had been scratching my head over it for a long time.

Answer (score 2):

Use the regular expression \r\n\Z.

Search > Find in Files. You're looking for \r\n\Z, replace with nothing, and make sure Regular Expression is checked at the bottom.

Comment: This worked for me, not the accepted answer.